# NetSuite for Outlook

Tags: outlook, netsuite

[image]I'm trying to install NetSuite for Outlook, but during the installation it throws an error because the 'certificate or its site is not trusted' (see attached image for full error).

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a question for Celigo support.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you need to contact add-in developers. They can guide you how to add a trusted publisher with their certificate.

You can use the command-line tool `CertMgr.exe` to add a publisher's certificate to the `Trusted Publishers` store on a client computer. See [How to: Add a trusted publisher to a client computer for ClickOnce applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-add-a-trusted-publisher-to-a-client-computer-for-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2019) for more information.